# Upload timeout in Chrome when using script to upload to GCP

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a script that suppose to upload my customers files from this page demo.dupleplay.com to my Google Cloud Platform Storage, the point that I create the script for is letting my customers upload their files on my storage without giving them the access to the Bucket. Just like Uptobox and Media Fire and those service but I did connect my service to my Google Cloud Storage instead of a normal server.

the problem is only when uploading remotly to the upload page (link provided above) the Chrome browser is giving an Network error just like when the server have a lot of traffic but it's not, any another browser is handling the upload correctly without any issue, how can I fox that with chrome?

This is the used script: https://storage.googleapis.com/duple-play.appspot.com/Archive.zip

Comment: What error? What script? More details please :)

Comment: Check this script https://storage.googleapis.com/duple-play.appspot.com/Archive.zip